# Checked listview for duplicates

Tags: vb.net

Hi Can you please help me to solve this i want to find the duplicates in listview. This is my code

```
 For Up As Integer = lvCart.Items.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
  For down As Integer = 0 To Up - 1 Step 1
   If lvCart.Items(Up).SubItems(0).Text <> lvCart.Items(down).SubItems(0).Text Then
    ExecuteQry("INSERT INTO tblPurchaseOrder VALUES ('" & lvCart.Items(Up).SubItems(0).Text & "','" & dateCreated & "','" & txtTcost.Text & "','" & lblUserid.Text & "')")
    ExecuteQry("INSERT INTO tblPurchaseOrder VALUES ('" & lvCart.Items(down).SubItems(0).Text & "','" & dateCreated & "','" & txtTcost.Text & "','" & lblUserid.Text & "')")
    Exit For
   Else
  End If
 Next
Next
```

if the nested loop found the same PONumber(lvCart.Items().SubItems(0).Text) in the listview it will be save as one transaction my code is working, it saves in the database but it show an error for duplicates

Answer (score 1):

To find duplicates in your list view you can use a Dictionary to help with that.  The itemDict will have no duplicates, and the duplicateItems list will contain duplicate items if you need them for some reason.

```
 Private Sub FindListViewDups()

    Dim lvCart As New ListView
    lvCart.Items.Add("hi")
    lvCart.Items.Add("bye")
    lvCart.Items.Add("hi")

    Dim itemDict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim duplicateItems As New List(Of String)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lvCart.Items.Count - 1

        If Not itemDict.ContainsKey(lvCart.Items(i).Text) Then
            itemDict.Add(lvCart.Items(i).Text, "")
            'Other non-duplicated logic goes here....
        Else
            duplicateItems.Add(lvCart.Items(i).Text)
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```